# Can't set capabilities inside a Docker container

Tags: c, docker

In order to run some software only compatible with Ubuntu 14.04, I want to deploy it inside a Docker container so that it has all the required dependencies.

The problem comes when this software tries to set capabilities on an executable (cap_ipc_lock, cap_net_raw, cap_sys_nice, cap_net_admin). Upon execution, I got an `` Failed to set capabilities on file `path_to_file' (Operation not permitted) `` message (see code below).

From the Docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities) I found that a container runs by default with a limited set of capabilities but it's possible to specify which ones are needed. But even if I run it with `--cap-add=ALL` I still got the error. Here is the couple lines of C code setting the capabilities, if it helps:

```
// Create capability set
const char *cap_text = "cap_ipc_lock=ep cap_net_raw=ep cap_sys_nice=ep cap_net_admin=ep";
  cap_t cap_d = cap_from_text(cap_text);
  if (cap_d == NULL) {
    perror("cap_from_text");
    return -1;
  }

  // Set file capability
  int retval = cap_set_file(EXECUTABLE, cap_d);
  if (retval != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to set capabilities on file `%s' (%s)\n", argv[1], strerror(errno));
    return -1;
  }
```

Any idea on how to make this work? Thanks

Edit:
For those who may face the same problem, I found a solution. I didn't work because everything (source code, executables, etc) were in a host folder mounted inside the container (-v option). Copying everything directly inside the container solved the problem.

Comment: Try with `docker run --privileged ....` and see if it works for you

Comment: Tried it already, I should have mentioned it

Comment: any error code and explanation that helps?

Comment: Apart from what I have mentioned in the question, not really. I'll try to post a minimum example code

Comment: After some digging I found that the program executes just fine when started using sudo dut doesn't when run as a normal user with the setuid bit set by root (should be the normal behavior)